# Keynote 6.6 cannot open old file, says: "<yourfile.key> cannot be opened for some reason."

Tags: macos, keynote

I've found that Keynote after upgrading to 6.6 could not open some of my previously created presentations anymore. How do I revert to a previous version?

Comment: Have you tried to import rather than open? Was the Keynote file from a recent version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that reverting to 5.5.3 solves the issue. I can now open my old presentation again.

There are two ways you can do that:

1. If you use time machine: Use that to find the old Keynote.app file (~550Mb) and restore it
2. If you don't have a backup of your own.. Find a torrent for Keynote 6.5.3. The version I found there works for me. You'll want to delete or compress and set aside the faulty 6.6. version before you put the old version in your applications folder.

Comment: Perhaps try a more legal method? Download Keynote from the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

Apple released Keynote 6.6.1 today - I tried to open previous files before and after updating, and sure enough, the files that previously would not open in 6.6 actually opened in 6.6.1.

Comment: Yes. Inch by inch, update by update, the file compatibility get to where we're not needing to remember which version of what suite created which document.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue! Downloaded keynote to find it would not open. Could not upgrade to 6.6 on Yosemite. It could be read in Preview so was able to rebuild - not ideal but quicker than uploading to ElCapt with poor wifi connection and limited time.